# Android webview not displaying '%' character

Tags: android, html, webview, loaddata

I have a `WebView` using following code:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(cont);
webView.loadData("Red 20%", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

It is having trouble showing the string. But if I remove the **'%' character** from the string it is showing properly. What is wrong with the code? How do I display '%' in `WebView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(cont);
webView.loadData("Red 20&#37;", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

You can see the special characters here:
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Answer (score 1):

URL encode the %

20%25 should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

An easier alternative is to use `TextUtils.htmlEncode()` for the strings you want to display.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(cont);
String s = TextUtils.htmlEncode("Red 20%");
webView.loadData(s, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: htmlEncode cannot make it encoded so that it gives a display in WebView. But I need a automated method with can convert all such char. encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `%` you have to useits equevalent to show it in web. actually it is `&#37` so that your code should change to

```
webView.loadData("Red 20&#37;", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "Red 20%" -> "Red 20 %"